# Difference between Mobile App installs and Daily Active Users (DAU)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-insights

I have a game that uses Facebook login and publish features. But my doubt is when I see Insight section, I found that the Mobile App Install are around 1500 but the Daily active users (DAU) is only around 883. According to my understanding the DAU has to be higher than the App Installs.

Can anyone clarify these. Also I need to verify that I haven't implemented anything wrong in the SDK implementation. I have the game both in iOS and Android, both uses Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it properly.

App Installs = the total number of people who have installed your app ever.

DAU = the number of people per day that use your app.

DAU will always be less than App Installs. You can't have more people using the app than have it installed.

N.B. it is not Daily Active Uses. It is Users. It's counting the number of people using the app not the number of times the app is used. One user may use the app 100 times but still you'll only get a DAU of 1.

Comment: I got app installs of 1483 on Feb 18 and the DAU on the same day was 883. It is not the total App install ever

Comment: Still though, just because someone installs your app doesn't mean they will use it. Also, people will inevitably uninstall an app so although you may have had 1483 app installs in a day it may not be the case that they all remained installed.

Comment: I call the [FBSettings publishInstall:myAppId] method in applicationDidBecomeActive. But my game has guest mode and FB mode. So only when player chooses to login as FB user, the FBLogin will be called. Will that cause a problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what the problem is? DAU and App Installs are entirely independent from each other. There is no rule that says DAU has to be higher than App Installs.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

DAU is the number of people that use your app or consume content from your app on a daily average.

Mobile App Installs are the number of times your app has been "installed". And it is unique per app install. Mobile app installs are reported by attempting to open a session.

**Explanation**

DAU is the number of people that use your app on a daily average.

How facebook defines a user as "active" is:

> A user is active when they view or engage with your app or your app's
>   content. The Key Sources displayed on the Insights Dashboard indicate
>   how many users are considered active for each activity source.
>   Activity sources for apps include:
>
> Users that visit your app's canvas page
>
> Users that view your app tab on a Page
>
> Users that published to News Feed (stream) through your app
>
> Users that "Liked" a stream story from your apps
>
> Users that commented on a stream story from your app

Taken from https://www.facebook.com/help/399262596797358/

Further more, Facebook autopublishes the install whenever you try to open an

```
FBSession
```

object. Their code inside the sdk is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithAppID:(NSString*)appID
        permissions:(NSArray*)permissions
    defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
    urlSchemeSuffix:(NSString*)urlSchemeSuffix
 tokenCacheStrategy:(FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy*)tokenCachingStrategy {

.
.
.
[FBSettings autoPublishInstall:self.appID];
}
```

Which, if you followed the tutorial, is called from the open session methods such as

```
+openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI
+openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:
```

So even if a user doesn't login to your app, the install is reported (because you need to call

```
openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO
```

To be able to implement Single Sign-On.